# how to retain the last value of the label binded to a numeric updown after clear()?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

I have a NumericUpDown in my Form and a Label which changes the value depending on the NumericUpDown value change event. I also have a clear Button which clears the NumericUpDown and a save Button because my form is connected to a database.

What is happening is when I press the up in NumericUpDown the value of the Label decreases and vice versa. It works like what I wanted to. Now, what I'm trying to do is whenever I click the clear Button I want the last value of the Label to be retained. Let's say, the last value of the Label is 80 and I changed the value of the NumericUpDown to 20 so the value of the Label now  is 60 when I press the clear I want the value of the Label to be 80 again and clear the NumericUpDown since I didn't click the save button I just cleared the NumericUpDown.

Below is my code for the NumericUpDown value changed.

```vb
Static num As Integer = 100
Static oldvalue As Integer

If numCategory.Value > oldvalue Then

    num -= 1

    lblpoints.Text = num.ToString

ElseIf numCategory.Value < oldvalue Then
    num += 1
    lblpoints.Text = num.ToString

Else

    lblpoints.Text = ""

End If

oldvalue = numCategory.Value
```

This is the code for clear Button but the problem with this is after I click the save Button it fires my if statement above so after a save has been done it increments the Label by one.

`numCategory.Value = nothing`

So I used this instead

`numCategory.ResetText()`

Comment: So are you using the NumericUpDown only for the arrows?

Comment: yes. How can I do that?

Comment: What prevents you from using the NumericUpDown to also display the number?

Comment: I'm using the value of the NUD as the points to be inserted in a database and I'm using the label as a display on how many points are left for the user. So what I'm trying to do is whenever I clear the value of the NUD I want the last value of the label to be displayed not the original value.

Comment: Let's say for example I increase the value of the NUD to 20  the label should become 80 and I got it working BUT if I click the "clear" button which has this code `numCategory.ResetText()` to clear the NUD the label stays at 80. What I want to happen is it should also reset to whatever value it has before the `numCategory_ValueChanged event.`

Comment: The default value of the label is 100. whenever I increase the value of the NUD it should subtract 1 from the label and whenever I decrease the value of NUD it should add 1 to the label. The minimum value of NUD is 0 and Max is 100 I got that working pretty right.